# How do I allow Cognito users access to private content on my AWS static S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I have spent weeks going in circles over this.  I have a static S3 website with several 'folders'.  I would like to allow public access to the 'root' and 'public' (css, javascript, etc.) folders, but want to restrict access to a 'user' folder.
I set up a User Pool & Group in Cognito that works well for my users (JWTs for customer usernames), but I am having one heck of a time connecting the dots!  I have tried using the IAM policy (below), but I know I'm doing something wrong. Would love any suggestions on where to go from here...
Anyone see errors on my policy language?  Will a policy similar to this work despite having "Block All Public Access" enabled?

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAccessToMyBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": [ "", "public/*" ],
                    "s3:delimiter": [ "/" ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAccessToUserFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [ "s3:GetObject" ],
            "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/user" ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [ "${aws:username}/*" ],
                    "s3:delimiter": [ "/" ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html) help?

Comment: I tried it.  Several iterations, but nope.  Thank you for trying!

Comment: Did you solve this? facing something similar at the moment